# On the completeness of $2^M$ for complete $M$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $M$ be a metric space, and

$$2^M=\{A\subset M\mid A\textrm{ is compact and not empty}\}.$$

Given $A\in2^M$ and $\epsilon>0$, define

$$N(\epsilon,A)=\{x\in M\mid d(x,a)<\epsilon\textrm{ for some }a\in A\},$$

and for any $A,B\in 2^M$ let

$$H(A,B)=\inf\{\epsilon>0\mid A\subset N(\epsilon,B)\textrm{ and }B\subset N(\epsilon,A)\}.$$

Show that if $(M,d)$ is complete, then $(2^M,H)$ is also complete.

**What I've tried**

Let $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^\infty\subset2^M$ be a Cauchy sequence. Then, given $\epsilon>0,$ $\exists N$ such that $n,m\geq N\Rightarrow A_n\subset N(\epsilon,A_m)$ and viceversa(*). Define

$$S=\{\{a_i\}_{i=1}^\infty\subset M|a_i\in A_i\textrm{ and }\{a_i\}_{i=1}^\infty \textrm{ is a Cauchy sequence}\}.$$

By (*), $S$ is not empty. Since $M$ is complete, every $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^\infty\in S$ converge to some point in $M$. So, let $L=\{\lim_{i\to\infty} a_i|\{a_i\}_{i=1}^\infty\in S\}$.

That's pretty much what I've got. I believe that $A_i\to L$, but I'm clueless about how to prove that. I don't even know how to prove that $L\in 2^M$.

An idea is to use the concepts of $\lim\inf$ and $\lim\sup$: Given any sequence $\{A_i\}_{i^1}^\infty\subset 2^M$, define

$$\lim\inf A_i=\{x\in M|\textrm{for each open set }U\textrm{ such that }x\in U, U\cap A_i\neq\emptyset\textrm{ for all but finitely many }i\textrm{'s}\},$$

$$\lim\sup A_i=\{x\in M|\textrm{for each open set }U\textrm{ such that }x\in U, U\cap A_i\neq\emptyset\textrm{ for infinitely many }i\textrm{'s}\}.$$

It can be shown that for arbitrary $M$, $A_i\to A\Rightarrow \lim\inf A_i=\lim\sup A_i=A$. However, the only proof I know for the converse is for compact $M$. So that seems like a dead end.

Comment: I don't think the reasoning so far is correct - what if each $A_i$ is the same compact set, and you choose a sequence $(x_i)$ in this compact set which doesn't converge?

Comment: @DanielSchepler You're right, edited, thanks.

Comment: A very minor note: You have to restrict $H(A, B)$ to $A\ne \phi \ne B$ unless $M=\phi.$ For if $A=\phi\ne B$ then  there is no $\epsilon$ such that $B\subset N(A,\epsilon).$

Comment: I recall seeing a very long proof in a text on fractals, where they were considering Cauchy sequences (in this metric) of the form $A_n=f^n(A)$ where $M$ is compact, $A$ is closed, and $f:M\to M$ is continuous.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[These very detailed notes](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/SeniorProject_KatieBarich.pdf) (a student project) has all the details for this result, including all definitions and some examples. The limit for a Cauchy sequence $(A_n)$ is the set of all limits of sequences $(a_n)$ where $a_n \in A_n$, so basically your set $L$, as Cauchy is equivalent to convergent in $(X,d)$. As a bonus you get a proof there that $X$ compact implies $2^X$ compact as well.